# Determining the irreducible invariant subspaces of a permutation action by computing eigenspaces of a matrix

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, group-actions, invariant-theory

Let $\Sigma\subseteq\mathrm{Sym}(n)$ be a *permutation group* on $N:=\{1,...,n\}$.
My goal is to determine the irreducible invariant subspaces of the permutation action of $\Sigma$ on $\Bbb R^n$, and I wonder whether the following technique always works.

---

Consider the element-wise action of $\Sigma$ on the subsets $\{i,j\}\subseteq N$ for $i,j\in N$.
Let $o(i,j)$ denote the *orbit* of $\{i,j\}$ w.r.t. this action, and let $\mathcal O(\Sigma)$ denote the set of all these orbits.

Now let $R:= \Bbb R[\,x_o\!\mid\! o\in\mathcal O(\Sigma)\,]$ be the *polynomial ring* over $\Bbb R$ with one variable $x_o$ for each orbit, and consider the matrix $M\in R^{n\times n}$ with components $ M_{ij} = x_{o(i,j)}$.

> **Question**: Is is true that that the eigenspaces of this matrix $M$ are exactly the irreducible invariant subspaces of the permutation action of $\Sigma$ on $\Bbb R^n$?

The matrix is symmetric, and thus the eigenspaces are real and mutually orthogonal.
Each eigenspace is indeed $\Sigma$-invariant, but is it also irreducible?

I have applied this idea computationally and it never failed me.
In practice, I do not use variables $x_o$, but some algebraically independent number (or just some random numbers). But does it work always?

Comment: The orbits of $G$ on pairs $\{x,y\}$ of points in the domain are called orbitals. The matrices associated with the orbitals span the centralizer algebra. The matrix $M$ in your question is somehow a generic element of the centraliser algebra. Thinking about the permutation representation with respect to a basis in which it is a direct sum of irreducible representations, you can work out an explicit description of the centraliser algebra - the books of Wielandt or Cameron, both called "Permutation groups", should have details.

Comment: If the answer to your precise question is not 'yes' then some minor modification should be true, though note the orbital matrices are not always symmetric.